# how to create a set of classes and its vars and methods from a given text in python

Tags: python, django, class

I want to create a set of classes, its vars and methodes just from a given text configuration, espcially with django models, for exmaple  i have a list of models to create in models.py

```
     classes=["users", "posts", "commnets"]
     vars= [{"a","b"},{"bb","vv"},{"aa"}]
     #methods=[{....},{....},{....}] not now
```

in models.py 
i want to make something like this to create that classes

```
for  i,j in zip(classes,vars):
    create_classes_from_string(i,j)
```

how  can i program #create_classes_from_string  assuring that it creates tables in my database with that configuration

Comment: Given no methods, do you want the classes to simply have those slots?  Should they be mutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can view this question in 2 perspectives

1. Normal way of dynamically creating python class
2. Create dynamic django models specifically

But in both cases, the attrs should be defined as dict with the variable name and its value. Because defining a variable without a value is meaningless here.

### 1. Normal way of dynamically creating python class

Here we can simply use **type()** method to generate a python class. This can be later used to create object with their own name by adding them to locals() builtin function.

An example is mentioned below

```
classes = ["Class1", "Class2"]

class_fileds = [
    {
        'cl1_var1': "test",
        'cl1_var2': 123,
    },
    {
        'cl2_var1': [1, 2, 3],
    }
]

classes_details = list(zip(classes, class_fileds))  # Python3 format

for class_details in classes_details:
    class_name = class_details[0]
    class_attrs = class_details[1]
    class_def = type(
            class_name,
            (object, ), # Base classes tuple
            class_attrs
        )
    locals().update({class_name: class_def})  # To associate the class with the script running

instance1 = Class1()
instance2 = Class2()
```

Outputs

```
>>> instance1 = Class1()
>>> instance2 = Class2()
>>>
>>> instance1.cl1_var1
'test'
>>> instance1.cl1_var2
123
>>> instance2.cl2_var1
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here the class names in the list, classes = ["Class1", "Class2"], can be used as such as given i.e. Class1(), Class2() etc. This is achieved by adding the variables Class1 and Class2 to the running script **dynamically by using local()** inbuilt function

### 2. Create dynamic django models specifically

Even though the basic logic remains the same there are a couple of changes required.

First of all we need to understand the dynamic model creations in Django. Django provides a clear documentation for this.

Please refer, https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

An example can be seen as below, you can directly add the below script to models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CharField, IntegerField

# This is taken from https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels#Ageneral-purposeapproach
def create_model(name, fields=None, app_label='', module='', options=None, admin_opts=None):
    class Meta:
        pass

    if app_label:
        setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)

    if options is not None:
        for key, value in options.iteritems():
            setattr(Meta, key, value)
    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}  # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class

    if fields: # Add in any fields that were provided
        attrs.update(fields)
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)  # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing

    return model


classes = ["Class1", "Class2"]

class_fileds = [
    {
        'cl1_var1': CharField(max_length=255),
        'cl1_var2': IntegerField(),
    },
    {
        'cl2_var2': IntegerField(),
    }
]

models_details = list(zip(classes, class_fileds))

for model_detail in models_details:
    model_name = model_detail[0]
    model_attrs = model_detail[1]

    model_def = create_model(
        model_name,
        fields=model_attrs,
        app_label=__package__,
        module= __name__,
    )

    locals()[model_name] = model_def
```

Output at django shell

```
>>> from my_app.models import Class1
>>> Class1(cl1_var1="Able to create dynamic class", cl1_var2=12345).save()
>>> Class1.objects.all().values()
<QuerySet [{'cl1_var1': 'Able to create dynamic class', 'id': 3, 'cl1_var2': 12345}]>
```

This model is added to django app, **my_app** and this would work fine and there are a few things to be noted

1. field attrs should be handled carefully as you are going to read that from text file
2. The models should be added using locals() to import that from app
3. Method, create_model should be taken from the reference link as it supports more features like adding admin pages etc
4. Data migration also works with this kind of model

### My Suggestion

The above-explained methods would work without any issue and all of them are supported but one thing to be not forgotten that, there is performance difference in dynamically imported classes and real import. Also, this is a bit complex structure and any change in the code should be done very carefully to not break it up.

So my suggestion is to **read the text file with configurations and generate models.py** file from the configuration file using some magic script(that can also be created in python).
So every time there is a change in the text-config file you have to generate the models.py script. This way you can also ensure the Model definitions