# How to create a class dynamically from a transformed argument collection

Tags: python

Pretty new to Python so the code below is pretty crude, mainly just for explaining what I have in mind.

What I am trying to do is create objects dynamically from database query. The query would return the fields needed to create the object. However, due to the use of ADO I need to transform the raw values before initialising the class.

Possible improvements to the pseudo code below would be to return the class name in the query and/or to use kwargs with the db column name as the key.

Using Python 3.6.

```py
def main():
  dbRow = GetAPersonRowFromDB()
  personFromRow = CreateObjectFromDatabase(Person, dbRow, "name", "gender")

def transform(value):
  transformedValue = #do something to the value
  return transformedValue

def CreateObjectFromDatabase(className, *args):
  transformedArgs = []
  # apply transform() to each *args item
  for arg in args:  

  transformedArgs.append(transform(dbRow[arg]))
  obj = className(transformedArgs)
  return obj

class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, gender):
    self.Name = name
    self.Gender = gender

  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.Name = args[0]
    self.Gender = args[1]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to reinvent the wheel, rather than just using SQLAlchemy or the like?

Comment: Probably you can refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742101/how-to-create-a-set-of-classes-and-its-vars-and-methods-from-a-given-text-in-pyt/57745183#57745183, this is what you are looking for, I think

Comment: @ShadowRanger this code needs to run inside TestComplete so at the moment I'm using their supplied solution to connecting with databases (i.e. ADO). I haven't tried yet but I understand that introducing 3rd party libraries is a pain but bossible. Will check SQLAlchemy, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using derived classes from a base class. I'm sure it can be done in a more elegant way but this works with minimal boiler plate code.

```py
# a dynamic object that gets constructed from kwargs
class DataObject(object):
  @classmethod
  def fromDictionary(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls(**kwargs) 

  @classmethod
  def type(cls):
    return cls.__module__    # will only work if each class is in its own module


class Person(DataObject):
  # DB column names must match parameter names
  def __init__(self, name, gender):
    self.Name = name
    self.Gender = gender


def CreateObjectFromDatabase(className, recRow):
  transformedArgs = {}
  for i in range(recRow.Fields.Count):
    item = recRow.Fields.Item[i]
    transformedArgs[str.lower(item.Name)] = TransformSomehow(item.Value)

  obj = className.fromDictionary(**transformedArgs)
  return obj

def main():
  dbRow = GetAPersonRowFromDB()
  personFromRow = CreateObjectFromDatabase(Person, dbRow)
```

Was playing around with using type() method to create the object e.g.

```py
type('Person', (DataObject, ), transformedArgs)
```

But this creates objects of Type 'type' which didn't work for my purpose.